# Changing onclick to onhover function?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found this script: http://www.queness.com/post/3036/create-a-custom-jquery-image-gallery-with-jcarousel

which has everything I need, there's just one more thing I need help with,

currently we click on the next and previous arrow to scroll the thumbnail but I want it to scroll upon hover the next and prev arrow. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the Javascript

```
$('.jcarousel-prev').on('click mouseenter', function() {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', '-=1');
});

$('.jcarousel-next').on('click mouseenter', function() {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', '+=1');
});
```

Comment: it is changing the behavior of the thumbnails and not the next and prev arrow

Comment: hahaha woops!  wasn't paying attention to what I was reading my bad.  All fixed.  @electron should be able to just plop that in somewhere (replace the current `.click()` calls with these)

Comment: You'll have to post all your Javascript, HTML and CSS (not the jQuery files, just the JS that you made and inline code in the page).  You can use http://www.jsfiddle.com to make it easy and share with us

Comment: i am using the same code given in the link, haven't made any changes.

Comment: You are missing something critical and I'm pretty sure it's the actual buttons in the HTML.  If I can't see the code you're using I really can't help any more :(

Comment: pls have a look at brushesnglasses.in/gallery.html

Comment: lol ok first, replace `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>` with `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` Then add my code to the end of the `$(document).ready(function() { ... code code ... here-> });`

Comment: It appears the jcarousel plugin actually loads everything AFTER the page finishes loading.  In this case, you'll have to put my code outside the code I mentioned above and place into it's own block like this:  `$(window).on('load', function() { ... click/hover code ... });`

Comment: Firefox debugger reports .on function not found.

Comment: And when i replaced the jquery-1.4.2.min.js link to the link you suggested the java script faltered.

Comment: Not entirely sure what made you use an `iframe` for your stuff but that's the page I was talking about, not the outer page (`index.html` not `gallery.html`)

Answer (score 1):

without seeing code i can only assume your syntax. try to swap out the `onclick` within the function to `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`. can you post a fiddle?